# Spring Oauth2 ResourceOwnerPassword flow for Single Sign on

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have an oauth Authserver app,a web app(enabled oauth sso),an android app(needs to access rest resources in the web app)

I am trying to implement spring-oauth2 taking example of oauth-vanilla(latest one with no jwt) spring boot sample project.The project has the following client configuration

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId: acme
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret: acmesecret
security.oauth2.client.authorized-grant-types: authorization_code,refresh_token,password
security.oauth2.client.scope: openid
```

so the logic flow goes like(correct me if am wrong) user attempts access to the ui app -->zuul proxied redirect(with client details) to authentication server-->login with credentials (protected /authorize url)-->authorize the scopes-->return with the token/authorization code.

How to eliminate the user authorization step(for android app purpose i want resource owner apporach).I changed my client configuration like this to follow

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("****").secret("*****").authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").scopes("read", "write");
```

but I am getting error from authserver app (**DefaultRedirectResolver.java**)

> "A redirect_uri can only be used by implicit or authorization_code
>   grant types."

if i have my security.oauth properties a below in my web-ui app

```
security:
  oauth2:    
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9097/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9097/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: ****
      clientSecret: ****
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9097/uaa/user
```

for single sign on ,can resource owner password approach be used or not ? if so what should i change as part of configuration?

Answer (score 4):

> "A redirect_uri can only be used by implicit or authorization_code
>   grant types."

I'm not sure about the "redirect_uri" but I don't think you can't get single sign on with the password flow. SSO is achieved by creating a session on the authorization server so that a client (same or different) won't have to authenticate again if the authorization server already has an authenticated session. The password flow doesn't create a session on the authentication server...it only gets tokens.

Comment: thanks for the response. So for the android purpose should I have different client?.more over the very same error thing is mentioned as improvement in spring issues.I will post the link

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `authorization_code` or `implicit` grant types on .authorizedGrantTypes(), for they are also ***redirect types***.

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("****").secret("*****").authorities("ROLE_USER")
.authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password", "refresh_token").scopes("read", "write");
```

or

```
clients.inMemory().withClient("****").secret("*****").authorities("ROLE_USER")
.authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "password", "refresh_token").scopes("read", "write");
```

Source:
[DefautlRedirectResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/DefaultRedirectResolver.java)